# Send cron jobs using algorithm?

Tags: php, cron

I'm working on a site in php. Is it possible to send cron jobs at times defined by an algorithm? Could I add such a functionally in the console or send it from my php script? I haven't used cron yet.

Comment: What do you mean? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @sarnold, I haven't work with cron jobs yet. I need some guidance to get started

Comment: @chris, it will be random within certain time sequences. rand() is php could I use that with cron?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that comes to the mind - run a cron job every minute with php script which generates random number in order to check whether to run the rest of the job.
This line in crontab will run cron job every minute (replace paths with yours)

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/job.php
```

Or if you can't directly call php, you may use curl or wget like that

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/curl --silent --compressed http://yoursite.com/job.php
```

And in your php file do whatever you want to check if it's time to run the rest of the job, like that:

```
if(rand(1, 60)==1)
{
 include 'the_actual_job.php';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your PHP script to be executed every hour, for example. Then add this code at the top of your script

```
sleep(rand(1, 60));
```

Now your script will be executed every hour + some seconds. It is random :)

Comment: sorry my question was misguiding. I need to send cron jobs at times defined by an algorithm. Where would I implement that code?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to schedule a job at a particular time you can use "cron"s friend "[at](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4087)" which will schedule a script a the time requested.

You simply fire off a command like:

```
$reqtime = '17.00'
system('at -f yourscript.sh ' . $reqtime);
```

And yourscript.sh will magically run at 17.00 today

Comment: thanks but how can i schedule the job at a time generated automatically by code?